# Cloudfront CDN with Lambda Imgproxy results in 429 Too Many Requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, imgproxy

I am using an image type Lambda function running `darthsim/imgproxy`, then I have a Cloudfront distribution that points to the public URL of the lambda.

Running this on my website (localhost or production with https), lets say 30-40 images on the page, if I use the function URL directly there is no issue, if I use the CloudFront URL I get HTTP error 429 for quite a few images, if I open one of the URLs that returned the error in a separate tab - it loads fine.

I've tried different origin policies for the CloudFront behavior, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and in my case, it was due to the Lambda function's concurrent execution limit set to 10. When the number of requests exceeded this limit, it resulted in HTTP 429 errors.

Here's what I did to resolve it:

1. **Increase Lambda Concurrency Limit:** You can request an increase to the Concurrent Executions limit from the [Service Quotas dashboard](https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home/services/lambda/quotas/L-B99A9384).  This should allow more simultaneous executions in that region, thereby handling more requests at a time without hitting the rate limit.
2. **Set up CloudFront Caching:** Made sure the CloudFront distribution behavior has cache policy configured to effectively cache the images. For me the default cache policy for Lambda functions was to disable caching. After switching to a Caching Optimized policy, performance improved as repeated requests for the same image were served from the cache, not triggering a Lambda execution.

Comment: I had caching but on some pages theres a burst of requests so still not suitable. I read about burst scaling and other scaling and from what I understood concluded that lambda is not suitable in this case. So I moved to imgproxy container in ECS.